# R: One page with many plots with a common legend of the LAST plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made 10 ggplots (barplots) in **R** and put them on the common page by using *ggarrange* function. I would like to have a common legend in the middle of the bottom of the page. The problem is that my plots are arranged in 2 columns (and 5 rows) where graphs with 4 colors are in the 1st column and graphs with 5 colors (of which 4 colors are common with colors of the graphs in the 1st column) are in the 2nd column.

Setting *ggarrange* parameter *common.legend=T* does not work properly, because it uses the legend of the 1st graph. So, then only 4 colors are there in the legend.

I would like to make a unique legend with all these 5 colors (and I do need to arrange plots in exactly that order).

Any suggestions? Thanks for all your help.

Here is an example code (with only 4 plots to be shorter):

```
# libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# example data
value = runif(n=36, min=0, max=2)
specie = c(rep(c(rep("Before", 4) , rep("After", 4)), 2),
           rep(c(rep("Before", 5) , rep("After", 5)), 2))
condition = c(rep(rep(c("cont" , "Be" , "Bc", "OZS"), 2), 2),
              rep(rep(c("cont" , "Be" , "Bc", "OZS", "Cm"), 2), 2))

# 1st graph
data1 = data.frame(specie=specie[1:8], condition= condition[1:8],
                   value=value[1:8])
data1$specie = factor(data1$specie, levels = c("Before", "After"))
data1$condition = factor(data1$condition,
                          levels = c("cont" , "Be" , "Bc", "OZS"))

g1 = ggplot(data1, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title="Treatment: ")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0,
                                  size = 10, face = "bold")) +        
  ggtitle("(a)") +                     
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Be" = "steelblue2",         
                               "Bc" = "gray47",
                               "cont" = "chartreuse3",
                               "OZS" = "indianred1")) 

# 2nd graph
data2 = data.frame(specie=specie[9:16], condition= condition[9:16],
                   value=value[9:16])
data2$specie = factor(data2$specie, levels = c("Before", "After"))
data2$condition = factor(data2$condition,
                         levels = c("cont" , "Be" , "Bc", "OZS"))

g2 = ggplot(data2, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title="Treatment: ")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0,
                                  size = 10, face = "bold")) +        
  ggtitle("(b)") +                     
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Be" = "steelblue2",         
                               "Bc" = "gray47",
                               "cont" = "chartreuse3",
                               "OZS" = "indianred1")) 

# 3rd graph
data3 = data.frame(specie=specie[17:26], condition= condition[17:26],
                   value=value[17:26])
data3$specie = factor(data3$specie, levels = c("Before", "After"))
data3$condition = factor(data3$condition,
                         levels = c("cont" , "Be" , "Bc", "OZS", "Cm"))

g3 = ggplot(data3, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title="Treatment: ")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0,
                                  size = 10, face = "bold")) +        
  ggtitle("(c)") +                     
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Be" = "steelblue2",         
                               "Bc" = "gray47",
                               "cont" = "chartreuse3",
                               "OZS" = "indianred1",
                               "Cm"= "darkgoldenrod1")) 

# 4th graph
data4 = data.frame(specie=specie[27:36], condition= condition[27:36],
                   value=value[27:36])
data4$specie = factor(data4$specie, levels = c("Before", "After"))
data4$condition = factor(data4$condition,
                         levels = c("cont" , "Be" , "Bc", "OZS", "Cm"))

g4 = ggplot(data4, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title="Treatment: ")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0,
                                  size = 10, face = "bold")) +        
  ggtitle("(d)") +                     
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Be" = "steelblue2",         
                               "Bc" = "gray47",
                               "cont" = "chartreuse3",
                               "OZS" = "indianred1",
                               "Cm"= "darkgoldenrod1")) 

# all graphs together
ggarrange(g1, g3, g2, g4,
          ncol=2, nrow=2, common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom")

# ... the 5th color is missing in the legend
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to add the missing factor level to `data1`:

```
data1$condition = factor(data1$condition,
                         levels = c("cont" , "Be" , "Bc", "OZS", "Cm"))
```

Then define the fill color for the new factor and add `drop = FALSE`:

```
g1 = ggplot(data1, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title="Treatment: ")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0,
                                  size = 10, face = "bold")) +        
  ggtitle("(a)") +                     
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Be" = "steelblue2",         
                               "Bc" = "gray47",
                               "cont" = "chartreuse3",
                               "OZS" = "indianred1",
                               "Cm"= "darkgoldenrod1"),
                    drop = FALSE)
```

Now the legend has all the fills:

```
ggarrange(g1, g3, g2, g4,
          ncol=2, nrow=2, common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom")
```

[image]